# How to properly supply legacy Firebase JWT token as "auth" to the REST API?

Tags: rest, authentication, firebase, jwt

I want to use Firebase REST API with custom database authentication tokens.
I took a *database secret* from project settings at console.firebase.google.com. According to that page, this secret can be used to "create custom database authentication tokens using a legacy Firebase token generator."
So I did what they say at https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html under "Generating a Token Without a Helper Library" and at https://jwt.io/introduction/:

```
header='{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
claims='{"v":0,"iat":1465114351,"exp":1465117951,"d":{"uid":"test"}}'
b64header=`echo -n $header | base64 -w 0`
b64claims=`echo -n $claims | base64 -w 0`
echo -n "$b64header.$b64claims."
echo -n "$b64header.$b64claims" | openssl sha256 -binary -hmac $SECRET | base64 -w 0
```

A token generated this way works properly (**200 OK**):

```
curl -v -o output.json -D output.txt "$URL/test.json?auth=$TOKEN"
```

But when I change just timestamps in the JWT claims,

```
claims='{"v":0,"iat":1465114158,"exp":1465117758,"d":{"uid":"test"}}'
```

I'm getting **400 Bad Request** with {"error" : "**Failed to validate MAC.**"} instead.

I noticed that:

1. In the "good" JWT there are no + signs
2. In the "bad" JWT there is a + sign in the signature part

But even if I url-encode the "auth" parameter,

```
curl -v -o output.json -D output.txt -G --data-urlencode "auth=$TOKEN" "$URL/test.json"
```

it still fails the same way.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base64 encoding is wrong, you need to use base64url which uses `/` for `+` and `_` instead of `-`. Also padding is stripped. The result is very different from url-encoding the overall string in the end.

```
header='{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
claims='{"v":0,"iat":1465114158,"exp":1465117758,"d":{"uid":"test"}}'
b64header=`echo -n $header | base64 -w 0 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`
b64claims=`echo -n $claims | base64 -w 0 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`
echo -n "$b64header.$b64claims."
echo -n "$b64header.$b64claims" | openssl sha256 -binary -hmac $SECRET | base64 -w 0 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'
```

The [JWT spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#page-6) defines the encoding as follows:

> Base64 encoding using the URL- and filename-safe character set
> defined in Section 5 of RFC 4648, with all trailing '='
> characters omitted (as permitted by Section 3.2) and without the
> inclusion of any line breaks, whitespace, or other additional
> characters.